# SQL ROLLUP or Union?

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

I am trying to get the grand total number of entries but unfortunately I am not convinced rollup would be the best choice:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME,
  PENDING_ITEMS,
  DATAGROUP
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE STATUS LIKE '%PROCESS%';
```

This Produces:

```
BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME     PENDING_ITEMS     DATAGROUP
PROCESSING DATA          34                PRODUCT
PROCESSING INS           40                SERVICE
```

I would like to get a Grand Total below, but ROLLUP is giving me subtotals because it includes the datagroup column. I just need the Grand total for the pending items but yet I need to display the datagroup. Would it be better to UNION with a sum(pending_items) select query?

```
BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME     PENDING_ITEMS     DATAGROUP
PROCESSING DATA          34                PRODUCT
PROCESSING INS           40                SERVICE
GRAND TOTAL **           74
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use ROLLUP  for better performance.If you need subtotal by using with group by clause.Refer this http://sql-plsql.blogspot.in/2010/10/rollup.html

Answer (score 3):

I would use `ROLLUP`, both for clarity and performance.

Say you have a sample table like this:

```
create table payments (business_status_name, pending_items, datagroup) as (
    select 'PROCESSING DATA', 10, 'PRODUCT' from dual union all
    select 'PROCESSING DATA',  5, 'PRODUCT' from dual union all
    select 'PROCESSING DATA',  2, 'SERVICE' from dual union all
    select 'PROCESSING INS',  10, 'SERVICE' from dual union all
    select 'PROCESSING INS',  10, 'SERVICE' from dual union all
    select 'PROCESSING INS',  10, 'PRODUCT' from dual
)
```

This is a way with `ROLLUP` (notice the parentheses to change the grouping logic):

```
SELECT BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME,
       SUM(PENDING_ITEMS) as PENDING_ITEMS,
       DATAGROUP
FROM PAYMENTS
GROUP BY ROLLUP ((BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME, DATAGROUP))
```

the result:

```
BUSINESS_STATUS PENDING_ITEMS DATAGRO
--------------- ------------- -------
PROCESSING INS             10 PRODUCT
PROCESSING INS             20 SERVICE
PROCESSING DATA            15 PRODUCT
PROCESSING DATA             2 SERVICE
                           47
```

the plan:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |     6 |   186 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP|          |     6 |   186 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PAYMENTS |     6 |   186 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME,
       SUM(PENDING_ITEMS) as PENDING_ITEMS,
       DATAGROUP
FROM PAYMENTS
GROUP BY BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME, DATAGROUP
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, SUM(PENDING_ITEMS), NULL
FROM PAYMENTS;
```

the result is the same than with `ROLLUP`:

```
BUSINESS_STATUS PENDING_ITEMS DATAGRO
--------------- ------------- -------
PROCESSING INS             20 SERVICE
PROCESSING INS             10 PRODUCT
PROCESSING DATA            15 PRODUCT
PROCESSING DATA             2 SERVICE
                           47
```

the plan is not so good, with `TWO FULL SCANS`:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |          |     7 |   199 |     7  (58)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL          |          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY     |          |     6 |   186 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| PAYMENTS |     6 |   186 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| PAYMENTS |     6 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is of course only a small example with a few records, no indexes, ... so things may be different on real tables, but I still believe `ROLLUP` should perform better than `UNION ALL`.

In a simpler case, exactly equal to yours, this will be the plans of the two approaches:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME,
       SUM(PENDING_ITEMS) as PENDING_ITEMS,
       DATAGROUP
FROM PAYMENTS
GROUP BY ROLLUP ((BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME, DATAGROUP))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |     2 |    62 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP|          |     2 |    62 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PAYMENTS |     2 |    62 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME,
       PENDING_ITEMS,
       DATAGROUP
FROM PAYMENTS
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, 
       SUM(PENDING_ITEMS),
       NULL
FROM PAYMENTS    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |          |     3 |    75 |     6  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL          |          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | PAYMENTS |     2 |    62 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| PAYMENTS |     2 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ROLLUP still has a better plan with a single table scan.

Comment: The important thing to notice, in comparing the plans, is not the "cost" (which should only be compared for different execution plans for **the same** query, not for two different queries that solve the same problem, both correct but using different approaches). The thing to notice is the fact that `union all` requires accessing the base table **twice**. Despite Gordon's contrary opinion (in the other answer), this is almost certain to make the `union all` query slower (and likely much slower) than the `rollup` query.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do agree with you about the cost but bear in mind, your result set is not exactly how I would like to display the data... It seems the rollup requires a further grouping which makes little sense... I only need the grand total for all rows, no further grouping required (considering the initial grouping has already been performed). Does this make sense?

Comment: @Rob_E: I can't get the point. Given my sample table, what should the result be?

Comment: Basically your sample table is a bit different from mine ... In the original example there no grouping by Datagroup ...

Comment: Just showed the same comparison without initial grouping

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rollup`, but you need an aggregation query:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME,
       SUM(PENDING_ITEMS) as PENDING_ITEMS,
       DATAGROUP
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE STATUS LIKE '%PROCESS%'
GROUP BY ROLLUP (BUSINESS_STATUS_NAME, DATAGROUP);
```

I doubt there is a performance difference between this an `union all`.  Note, however, that this is guaranteed to put the summary row as the last row in the result set.

Comment: I believe you need another couple of parentheses

Comment: `union all` will likely require reading the base table twice - why would there be no performance difference between that and reading it only once (with the `rollup` solution)?